# All drivers work perfectly when using 'Try Ubuntu', but wireless breaks after installation

Tags: wireless, drivers, system-installation, broadcom, live-environment

I have been able to boot and run Ubuntu perfectly off of my USB in 'Try it now' mode.  It lets me select the proprietary drivers for my Broadcom wireless on my Alienware 17 with no flaws.  After I install Ubuntu, selecting the drivers causes the system to start installation, then freeze the install bar.

The only difference I've been able to correlate is that during the live trial, I'm not asked for an administrator password to allow the non-open source driver.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Try with installing Common wifi device drivers containing package :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```